# Cython C++ and std::map handling

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am trying to interface my C++ class with Cython, but having difficulty passing as an argument std::map.

sample.pxd file:

```
from libcpp cimport bool
from libcpp cimport string
from libcpp cimport map
from libcpp.utility cimport pair


cdef extern from "../SampleProg.h":
        cdef extern from "<map>" namespace "std":
            cdef cppclass SampleProg:
            SampleProg() except +

            void setInitialTemplateParameters(map[string,XdmValue*] parameters, bool tunnel)

            # Get all parameters as a std::map
            map[string,XdmValue*]& getParameters()

            # Get all properties as a std::map
            map[string,string]& getProperties()
```

sampleProg.pyx file:

```
cimport sampleProg
from libcpp cimport bool
from libcpp cimport map
from libcpp.utility cimport pair
from libcpp cimport string

cdef class PySampleProg:

     def set_initial_template_parameters(self, bool tunnel, **kwds):

        cdef map[str, PyXdmValue ] parameters
        cdef bool c_tunnel
        c_tunnel = tunnel
        cdef PyXdmValue value_
        for key, value in kwds.items():
                if isinstance(value, PyXdmValue):
                        value_ = value
                        parameters[key] = value_.thisvptr

        if len(kwds) > 0:
            self.setInitialTemplateParameters(parameters, c_tunnel);
```

I cannot seem to find examples of constructing a map to pass to C++ in cython. I am getting this error in both the pxd and pyx file:

> void setInitialTemplateParameters(map[string,XdmValue*] parameters,
>   bool tunnel)
>
> ### ^
>
> sampleProg.pxd:186:46: 'map' is not a type identifier

Comment: I'm very puzzled by the nested `cdef extern from ...` in your pxd file. I doubt if you want the inner `<map>` one?

Comment: Thanks. I will remove it. As a result  of many examples on the web.

Answer (score 2):

This looks a bit of a mess and probably a little way from working. However, your "map is not a type identifier" error is easily explained. You want:

```
from libcpp.map cimport map
```

(i.e. `from libcpp cimport map` just gets the `map.pxd` file rather than the `map` C++ class defined within). The same applies to `string`.

Comment: Thanks. moved on now. But I had to to change the import to the following: `from libcpp.map cimport map`

Comment: Yes you're right. It's `cimport` rather than `import`